# Xamarin Android BLE - BluetoothAdapter.StartLeScan returning false

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

Referencing this guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html I'm trying to run the `BluetoothAdapter.StartLeScan(BluetoothAdapter.ILeScanCallback)` method. It is returning false and I'm not sure why.

In my manifest I have permissions enabled for `BLUETOOTH` and `BLUETOOTH_ADMIN`. I have confirmed this by running `Activity.ApplicationContext.CheckCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.BLUETOOTH")` and `Activity.ApplicationContext.CheckCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN")`. These both return `Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted` yet `BluetoothAdapter.StartLeScan(BluetoothAdapter.ILeScanCallback)` returns false.

What could be causing this to return false?

```
BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;

// activity set in class constructor

var res = activity.ApplicationContext.CheckCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.BLUETOOTH");
// returns Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted
var res2 = activity.ApplicationContext.CheckCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN");
// returns Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted

Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.PostDelayed(delegate
{
    adapter.StopLeScan(this);
}, 4000);

var boolerson = adapter.StartLeScan(this); // returns false... why?
```

Comment: I'm not using Xamarin, but I just had the problem of startLeScan returning false. For me the solution was point number 4 in the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515885/onlescan-never-gets-called-android

Comment: Unfortunately rebooting the device did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was that I was calling `BlutoothAdapter.StartLeScan(BluetoothAdapter.ILeScanCallback)` within a library I created. When I called it directly from my application code, it returned true. This seems like it shouldn't be, but it is.

Answer (score 0):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

These permissions are necessary.